# Error on compiling in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

```js
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
            
                
                
//App.js  


import React, { Component } from 'react'; //import logo from
'./logo.svg'; import './App.css';

import HeaderComponent from
'./Components/HeaderComponent/HeaderComponent'; 
import FooterComponent from './Components/FooterComponent/FooterComponent'; 
import Main from './Components/Main/Main';
const App = () =>  { 
  return(
     <div>
       <HeaderComponent />
       <Main />
       <FooterComponent />
     </div>   ) }
 
export default App;
```

Comment: Did you export `HeaderComponent`, `Main` and `FooterComponent` as default exports from their respective files?

Comment: I created all these components now

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is very clear, one of your imports is not importing a valid react component.

To fix this, make sure all your imports are exporting a react component, either a class or a function for stateless components.

you might have something like the following for each component.

```
export default HeaderComponent extends Component { ... }

export default Main extends Component { ... }

export default FooterComponent extends Component { ... }
```